# Is there a significant difference between the `spritesheet` & `texture-atlas` tags?

Tags: discussion

Is there a significant enough difference between [spritesheet](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spritesheet) & [texture-atlas](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texture-atlas) to warrant separate tags?

My understanding of the terms is that the former is more often applied in a 2D context whereas the later is more often associated with 3D, but I feel like I've seen exceptions in either direction. Do we need them both? Can a person be an expert in one, but not the other? Should one be a synonym for the other? Are there better options?

Presently, spritesheet has 174 questions, 22 followers & tag info, whereas texture-atlas has 87 questions, 2 followers & no tag info.

Comment: @Gnemlock Thanks. Odd that didn't turn up in the Related posts when I was submitting. And I didn't think to cross reference the top users - good call.

Comment: Oh, looks like Related posts are from Meta, whereas the post cited by @Gnemlock is from regular GDSE - just noticed as I tried to request close due to duplicate & wasn't allowed to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While sprite sheets are a kind of texture atlas, I think there is still utility in the separate tags because the contexts in which you use both terms sometimes (perhaps often) differ significantly enough.

Answer (score 2):

As per both request, and author confirmation that this does clarify parts of the question, I am reposting my comment as an answer;

ultimately, I believe the two tags are quite different from each other, and there is a distinction between the users who answer them. They should ***not*** be merged together.

---

#### The two terms are quite different from each other

Initially, I had never heard of a *texture atlas*, before. I have had some experience with *spritesheets*, but I had never even heard of the term *texture atlas*. I did not have to look far for a good definition; Somebody has already asked ["what is the difference between a sprite sheet and a texture atlas?"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/69895/what-is-the-difference-between-a-sprite-sheet-and-a-texture-atlas), here on the main site. The answer quite clearly defines a distinct *difference* between the two terms, and the author even comments on the asker's presumption that they are both the same.

> "A sprites-sheet (often refers to a large image that) is supposed to contain the animation frames of a specific 2d character or projectile in a game." ***...*** "A texture-atlas (is often taken to mean a large 2d image that) contains many textures."<sup>*[sic]*</sup> <sub>[- Answer submitted by Zehelvion](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/69898/63208)</sub>
>
> "Everything is that same, bits containing ones and zeroes." <sub>[- Further comment submitted by Zehelvion](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/69895/what-is-the-difference-between-a-sprite-sheet-and-a-texture-atlas)</sub>

I can see how there are some disctinct similarities between the two terms; but I would not use the term *"spritesheet"* to define a *texture atlas*, and I would not use the term *"texture-atlas"* to define a *spritesheet*.

---

#### There is a clear distinction between our top users

If we look at our top users for both [spritesheet](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/spritesheet/topusers) and [texture-atlas](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/texture-atlas/topusers), we see a distinct set of different users (with the exception of Kromster, who is in the top three for both. Excellent job!); this tells me that you very well *can* be an expert in one, and not the other - at least, within the scope of this website.

---

#### What further improvement could be made?

Can we make a further improvement? <del>Yes. It is clear that the two tags have *similarities*, though not enough to warrant merging them within the scope of this site. Perhaps we could improve usability by writing up a *guideline* for the [texture-atlas](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texture-atlas) tag; at present, it has none.</del> A guideline has now been published to the [texture-atlas](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texture-atlas) tag.